# cannot build an app in android studio using kotlin

Tags: compilation, daemon, failed-installation

java.io.filenotfoundexception: c:\users\jong1\androidstudioprojects\jon5\app\build\tmp\kotlin-classes\debug\com\scottishparanormal\jon5\mainactivity.class (the system cannot find the path specified)

Daemon compilation failed: null
java.lang.Exception
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:69)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.common.CompileService$CallResult$Error.get(CompileService.kt:65)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemon(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:247)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.compileWithDaemonOrFallbackImpl(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:178)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleKotlinCompilerWork.run(GradleKotlinCompilerWork.kt:138)
at org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction.execute(GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers.kt:76)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerServer.execute(DefaultWorkerServer.java:63)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:66)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1$1.create(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.internal.classloader.ClassLoaderUtils.executeInClassloader(ClassLoaderUtils.java:100)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.lambda$execute$0(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:62)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:44)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker$1.call(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.AbstractWorker.executeWrappedInBuildOperation(AbstractWorker.java:41)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.NoIsolationWorkerFactory$1.execute(NoIsolationWorkerFactory.java:59)
at org.gradle.workers.internal.DefaultWorkerExecutor.lambda$submitWork$0(DefaultWorkerExecutor.java:169)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runExecution(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:187)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.access$700(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:120)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner$1.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:162)
at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:31)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:114)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.runBatch(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:157)
at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue$ExecutionRunner.run(DefaultConditionalExecutionQueue.java:126)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)

keep getting this error. looked at everything and crossed checked but cant see why its giving this warning

tried clen build
but will not build

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.